# AWS Certificate Manager Requested a certificate reporting 'Renewal eligibility` Ineligible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I have just successfully been issues a certificate for a domain that is also hosted by route53. However it's coming up in the `Renewal eligibility` column as `Ineligible`. Tried to find what exactly this means and why however haven't found anything conclusive?

Anyone got any points for me here? What to make sure my certificate doesn't expire at some random point in time with out me noticing. Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 47):

As soon as I attached a cloudfront distribution to the certificate, the certificate was marked as in use and now `Eligible` for `Renewal eligibility`

Answer (score 0):

All other reasons are listed [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-ineligible):

> ACM certificates might be ineligible for renewal if any of the
> following are true:
>
> - The certificate isn't associated with another AWS service.
> - The certificate is expired.
> - The certificate is imported.
> - It's a private certificate issued with the IssueCertificate API call.